# ANTLR4: How to hide a specific character?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am new to ANTLR4 and have a trouble.

I want to have the code accept integers with _ between digits, but the output would not include _ characters. For example: it would accept 12_34_5 and the expected token would be 12345.

Is there a way to do that in ANTLR4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you mean by "output would not include _ characters" is to rewrite the text value of the recognized token. The "output" of a parse is a parse tree.

Use [a lexer action](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-actions).

CSharp:

```
grammar Rewrite;
everything: .* EOF;
Int: [0-9_]+ { Text = Text.Replace("_",""); };
WS: [ \n\r\t]+ -> skip;
```

Note, the "action code" is target-specific, i.e., in C# for the CSharp target. You will need to change the action code for another target.

Comment: Oh thanks, I have solved it with your idea.